# Spring Security (basic-authentication) - receiving 401 Unauthorized for correct credentials

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I am trying to add a basic authentication security layer over a REST service that I developed using Spring boot 4.3.

I have essentially did two main things:

1. Implement `UserDetailsService` interface to provide user details. Here I read from a text file the usernames and the encoded (via Bcrypt) passwords.
2. I declare a bean as follows in my `@EnableWebSecurity` annotated security configuration class:

   ```
   @Bean
   public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder () {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
   ```

   to return the specific password encoder.

I am testing the authentication using rest clients both ARC (for Chrome) and REST Client of Firefox.

The issue is as follows:

1. When I enter my credentials for the first time and upon successful authentication, the response is `200 OK`. This is true for a bunch of users. In other words, as long as I supply correct pair of credentials I get a `200` response.
2. But, after a single request with incorrect credentials the authentication process breaks down. Sometimes I get `200` and other times a `401` even for correct credentials. Other users authentication is affected as well, at this point of time.

There is a curious log that appears at step 2:

```
WARN 6813 BCryptPasswordEncoder : Empty encoded password
```

To elaborate a bit on the hashing of the passwords, I ran the Bcrypt password encoder utility and encoded a bunch of passwords and saved them manually in a text file for the corresponding user names.

I am unsure where the issue lies: whether the clients caching the credentials or the Spring security context caching the incorrect principal or the user details service breaking down (no such exception in the logs though).

Any help is appreciated. If you need any further specific information, please do let me know.